# Problems with fillable PDF in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

I am trying to create a fillable PDF form for work in LibreOffice Writer. It works just fine in Writer when I test it out, however when I export it as a PDF and open in Adobe Reader it no longer functions the same way.

For instance, I have date fields with drop-down calendars; these are replaced by simple text input boxes in the PDF version of the file. Another example, I have numerical fields; these also become text boxes in the PDF.

What is causing this? How do I fix it? I want the PDF file to look and work like the .odt file. Any insight is appreciated!

Thanks,
Laya

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile to look at what PDF forms are and do. PDF forms do primarily not make a difference between text, number, date etc. It is all text fields, and if you want to be specific, you have to provide the means to do so.

However, the conversion of drop downs selectors should be better, because there is the combobox field type which is a drop down.

If you want to allow only numerical entries in a text field, you have to set its Format properties accordingly.

In any case, what LibreOffice creates as PDF form is a base, and you will have to finish the form (particularly if you want/need logic) in Acrobat (Pro). Again, this is because the object models of .odt and PDF are too far apart that a conversion is possible.

LibreOffice/OpenOffice is a good low-cost way to create PDF forms, but you still need Acrobat to finish the PDF form.